# Is it possible for a C++ (vcxproj) project to reference a net5.0 C# project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, .net-5

I have a C# class library project which I consume from a C++ project. This works perfectly well when:

- the C# project has **TargetFramework** set to *netstandard2.0*
- the C++ project has **TargetFrameworkVersion** set to *v4.7.2*

However, I now need to upgrade the C# library to net5.0...

- the C# project has **TargetFramework** set to *net5.0*  (using new style project file)
- the C++ project has **TargetFrameworkVersion** set to *v5.0*

and receive this error....

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1806,5):
>
> error :  Project '..\cslib\cslib.csproj' targets 'net5.0'.
> It cannot
> be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v5.0'.

Note that it's not possible to set the **TargetFrameworkVersion** for the C++ project to "net5.0" or "net5.0-windows" since that results in a project load error:

[image: project load error]

It's not clear that "v5.0" is the correct [TFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) for a C++/vcxproj format file - it's possible msbuild is just falling back to v4.7.2 by default but I can't think of a better alternative.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  It *seems* like it should be possible to target net5.0 in a C++ project by now.  (I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Preview and **PlatformToolset** is set to *v143* which is the latest).

Comment: I see that you have removed a follow up from your question, which is good. You can create your own answer, detailing whatever insights you got beyond (and/or based on) the existing answer. Whatever is then still unclear you can discuss in a separate new question. In any case, accepting the answer (even if you found new problems....) seems appropriate. Sorry if this seems like preaching, I just want to help you find the best way on. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch.  After consideration I thought the best approach was to move the follow-up into PMF's  answer below since I think that makes it a more complete answer while keeping the question more focussed.

Comment: Allow me to express my opinion: Relevantly extending another users post is risky. They may not be pleased. Consider @-pinging them to notify them and ask for review. I consider the safe way to be adding your own answer, referring to the existing one and clearly state that you only want to add to something already helpful (as reflected by your acceptance-tick). The fact that this implies a chance for you to harvest some upvotes is well-earned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but the following should help:

If using the GUI, the following settings need to be made in properties: Under "Root->Extended" setting "Common language runtime support": "Net Core runtime support /clr:core" and ".NET Core Target framework": ".NET 5.0" (you might need to click "apply" after choosing the first, to get the possible settings in the second box to update)

In the .vxcproj, this results in:

```
...
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Keyword>ManagedCProj</Keyword>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and (once for each build configuration):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Note that it is not possible to create C++ exes in .NET Core. C++/CLI projects must be libraries and cannot contain the main entry point (create a stub-loader C# project if you have to).

You *may* then experience:

> error NETSDK1145: The Apphost pack is not installed

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1145) suggests this can be overcome by modifying the project file but if that does not work, a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file can be added in the solution root folder to point to the desired SDK.

Comment: What (if any) SDK version is specified in `global.json`?

Comment: I have appended some comments about the global.json to your answer-feel free to edit.

Comment: I'm fine as it is now.